# Unorder print out of echo in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't get why does this happen? In my **php** code I'm trying to echo **Job status** that retrieve database from **MySQL** with a function **newjob**. It prints Old***Job Status:** instead of **Job Status:** Old. Do client side and server side programming run at the same time or they have order to compile?

```
echo '<b>'.'Job Status: '.'</b>' .newjob($row['new_job'])."<br />";

function newjob($num) {
if($num == 1) {
echo "New";
}else{
    echo "Old";
    }
}
```

Comment: i think your function is execute before the echo statement that is why  else condition execute in that function and is echo the Old keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NEVER make your function output a value.**

But only **return** it.

```
echo '<b>'.'Job Status: '.'</b>' .newjob($row['new_job'])."<br />";

function newjob($num) {
    if($num == 1) {
        return "New";
    }else{
        return "Old";
    }
}
```

Comment: why NEVER make your function output a value? i use always return, but i like to know why?

Comment: It's because you often want to output to different devices (stdout, a file, a string, etc.) If you couple the function directly with stdout (as you are by using echo), then you'd have to use a workaround, like output buffering, to capture the usefulness of the function. If you stick to only returning a string, you can easily output to stdout, or a file. In other words, always returning a string from a function is output agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs to `return` rather than `echo`. When your function gets called, the first line expects it to return a value that can be concatenated, but the function doesn't return anything, it merely `echo`s on invocation.

```
function newJob( $num ) {
    return $num == 1 ? "New" : "Old";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<b>'.'Job Status: '.'</b>' .newjob($row['new_job'])."<br />";

function newjob($num) {
if($num == 1) {
return "New";
}else{
    return "Old";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
echo '<b>Job Status:</b> ', newjob($row['new_job']), '<br>';
function newjob($num) {
    return ($num ? 'New' : 'Old');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This style of programming could be avoided with an ORM such as [Propel](http://propelorm.org/). Instead of creating a standalone function, you can create another accessor that can return the "Old" or "New" string based on the state of the "Job" object.

That way, you can use the string getNewDescription() (the method that you have there) or boolean isNew() and it will be driven from the same data.